# Sequence of functions uniformly/absolute/normal convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I've got this sequence of functions...

$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$

To show:

1. The sequence is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$
2. It is NOT uniformly convergent in compact intervals [a,b] that contain zero.

Additional exercise:

3. In which compact intervals is the sequence uniformly convergent
4. In which compact intervals is the sequence NOT normal convergent
5. Calculate the sum-function of the sequence

What I got:

First I tried to calculate the limit (in form of a function) to which the sequence converges. In this case (because it's a geometric sequence) the limit is

$f(x) = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=1+x^2$

From what i can determine no interval [a,b] with $a<0<b \vee a,b = 0$ can be uniformly convergent because $\forall n\in \mathbb{R},x=0 : \frac{0^2}{(1+0^2)^n}=0$

Therefore the limit in this point must be zero and can never be, as the limit function suggests, be 1 ($1+0^2=1$)

So is it right to deduct that every other interval is uniformly convergent? At least it seems like it, is there a way to check?

**(2) check**

Next i tried to show that the sequence of functions is absolute convergent by using the ratio test. It gives me $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{1}{1+x^2}| < 1$ which is true for all x except x = 0.

The question states otherwise though. It must be true for ALL x.

**(1) check?**

(3) is just like (2) somehow. The answer: For all intervals without x.

**(3) check?**

I've no clue for (4) :(

**(4) OPEN**

For the last one: The Sum-function. It you're not familiar with it, it is just a function that lets you get the value of the sequence ASAP. E.G. $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{M} n = n*\frac{n+1}{2}$

In my case, it's just the limit-function isn't it?

**(5) check**

Do you have any helpful recommendations, helpful clues or improvements in mind that would help me?

Best regards.

Comment: what do you mean by normally convergent? also, you are using "sequence" for "series"

Comment: @zhw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better if you write $$f_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}{x^2\over (1+x^2)^n}=(1+x^2)^{N+1}-1$$and $$f(x)=\lim_{N\to \infty}f_N(x)$$the your arguments become **preciser and easier**.

**Hint for $(4)$**

By differentiation we obtain that the maximum  of $x^2\over (1+x^2)^n$ is $${(n-1)^{n-1}\over n^n}\sim{1\over e}\cdot {1\over n-1}$$so the question is: what happens if an interval contains $0$ or does **not** contain zero?

Comment: That's true. Apart from that, did you spot any major mistakes?
How did you get (n-1)^(n-1)/n^n?? 
Well if the interval contains zero, the upper equation wouldn't work

Comment: I think the sum-function should be the same geometric series you calculated as $f(x)=1+x^2$.<br><br> Now, for your second question, the maximum happens at $x=\pm\sqrt{1\over n-1}$ and the maximal value becomes$$\max f(x)={(n-1)^{n-1}\over n^n}$$<br><br>For your third question, note that if an interval contains $0$, then it contains either $\pm\sqrt{1\over n-1}$ and then $$\sup_{[a,b]}|f(x)|={(n-1)^{n-1}\over n^n}$$which sum up to $\infty$ clearly, but if the interval does **not** contain $0$, and without loss of generality we assume $0<a<b$ then (to be continued...)

Comment: (cont'd) $$\sup_{[a,b]}|f(x)|={a^2\over (1+a^2)^n}$$ for large enough $n$ which sum up to a bounded number and guarantee normal convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Your welcome. Wish you luck!!